# Area of a special triangle in a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, recreational-mathematics, plane-geometry, quadrilateral

As is the case with triangles, I am sure that there is an entire ocean of not-so-well-known theorems about Euclidean quadrilaterals. In particular, I am interested in the following problem and suspect the existence of a theorem that elegantly trivializes it (the black points are the mid-points of the respective sides). What would that theorem be?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Call the midpoint of $BC$ $M$ and midpoint of $AD$ $N$, and $P$ the intersection of $AM$ and $BN$, and $Q$ the intersection of $MD$ and $CN$. Let $t$ and $y$ be the areas of triangles $PMN$ and $QMN$ respectively. Then: $t+81 = y+72$ and $t+49 = y+x$. Thus: $32 = 72 - x \implies x = 40$.

Comment: Thanks! Thing is, I can see that the answer can be worked out using basic geometric arguments. My question is more about theorems about general quadrilaterals that would trivialise such and similar problems. The focus in the question is on those theorems, not the particular numerical answer to this problem.

Comment: The theorem you are looking for is: Given $\triangle ABC$, let $M$ be the midpoint of $BC$, then $\text{area} \triangle ABM = \text{area} \triangle ACM$. I used this theorem in this problem.